# Uploading 100KB+ zip files gives an Internal Server Error

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, centos

Here's my HTML code although I think it's irrelevant:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="../developers/submit.php" method="post">
<input name="product_zip" type="file" /><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="20000">
</form>
```

The reason I say it's irrelevant is that I can upload zip files under 100kb.  I get a 500 internal server error on zip files over 100kb.  Everything else works over 100kb, png, gif, newly created zip files, etc.

I've checked all my PHP ini settings.  Everything is right including max upload size, execution time, etc.

I'm baffled on this one and can't figure out why my server won't upload certain zip files.  It's not my PHP code, because I have completely commented it out and still get a 500.

Server Info:

- Cpanel / WHM
- CentOS 5
- PHP /w mySQL

**SOLUTION FOUND:**
It was a problem with mod_fcgid.

The  MaxRequestLen needs to be set higher.

The solution is here: http://pivica.me/blog/500-internal-server-error-while-uploading-files-bigger-then-100kb-modfcgid-problem

Comment: Have you looked at your webserver error logs?

Comment: Have you bothered checking your logs yet?

Comment: The error logs are blank.  I just noticed that it's zip files over 100kb that are not working.

Comment: webserver cannot throw Internal Server Error without any reason. Seems like you have your errors logging turned off

Comment: I just checked my httpd.conf and the error logging was not commented out, is there somewhere else it would be turned off?

Comment: @Chris: may be php error logging?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had multiple error logs and I was looking at the wrong one.  Found it and it was giving me mod_fcgid errors.

Comment: Answers belong in the answer box.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: I cannot answer my own question yet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with mod_fcgid.

The MaxRequestLen needs to be set higher.

The solution is here: http://pivica.me/blog/500-internal-server-error-while-uploading-files-bigger-then-100kb-modfcgid-problem

Answer (score 1):

Problem is the file extension running on hosting server you need to remove the "FastCGI" on some hosts for etc "PHP5.2.x + FASTCGI" change it to "PHP5.2.x" IN file extension manager

Answer (score 0):

MAX_FILE_SIZE is just 20kb, try increasing the MAX_FILE_SIZE variable and see if it changes anything

Answer (score 0):

The **MAX_FILE_SIZE** and **MaxRequestLen** update should work! HOWEVER, if not go into your "php.ini" configuration folder and update each individual (requires apache reset) as in order in the below list until you can upload the zip file:

- upload_max_filesize
- post_max_size
- max_input_time
- default_socket_timeout

And if *STILL* neither work. Try turning on "extension=php_zip.dll" within that same php config file.