# Internal Server Error on PHP file uploading script godaddy

Tags: php, permissions

I made a really simple file uploading script on my website on godaddy but it keeps giving me an "Internal Server Error" whenever I try to upload a file

The script works and it displays all the errors like "your file is too big" as it should

I have enabled file_uploads in the PHP settnings but is there any thing else i need to activate to get it to work?

Like file writing permissions?

Comment: if you're getting a 500 error, you'll have to check the server's error logs for more details. A few minutes of poking around in there will save everyone here having to play 20 questions trying to guess what might be wrong.

Comment: Take a look at [Uploading 100KB+ zip files gives an Internal Server Error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6970317/2752041), it should give you some insights.